# Checkout takes 2 minutes to redirect to Sagepay form

Tags: magento

Apologies if I am posting this in the wrong section.

We have a Magento CE 1.9.1.0 site and have recently purchased a one page checkout extension. The checkout looks great and has lots of neat features but when proceeding to Sagepay for payment, it takes 2-3 minutes to redirect which is simply to long.

We have a support ticket raised with the extension developer but still no update 10 days down the line.

Just wondering if anybody has any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?